# Qubo: Energy of of Non Overlapping Constraint in Taillard's Job Shop Problem

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research, constraint-programming

Suppose we have a set of tasks $T = \{t_1, t_2, \dots, t_n\}$ with durations $\{d(t)| t \in T\}$, that need to be executed on some machine such that their execution times do not overlap.
We can represent the start time of task $t$ as $x(t),\, x \in \mathbb{N}$. We don't care about the execution order.

[image: Taks Schedule]

Regardless whether this problem is trivially solved by just exceuting each task after previous ends, I'd like to encode this constraint as minimizing a polynomial $p: X \times \Xi \to \mathbb{R}$ where $X = \{x(t) : t \in T\}$ and $\Xi$ denotes the set of *any extra variables* one might need to introduce.

Currently my approach is to use the classic double well in combination with slack variables:

For each pair of tasks $(t_i, t_j)$, we want that $x(t_i) + d(t_i) \leq x(t_j)$ **or** $x(t_j) + d(t_j) \leq x(t_i)$. Introducing the slack variable $\xi \geq 0$, this translates to
$$x(t_i) + d(t_i) + \xi - x(t_j) = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad x(t_j) + d(t_j) + \xi - x(t_i) = 0$$
Multiplying both options and squaring gives
$$
p_{ij}(x, \xi) = (x(t_i) + d(t_i) + \xi - x(t_j))^2(x(t_j) + d(t_j) + \xi - x(t_i))^2.
$$

It is easy to check that $p_{ij}$ is minimized iff tasks $t_i$ and $t_j$ do not overlap and that $0$ is the global minimum value. Thus summing over all combinations of tasks gives the desired constraint energy for all tasks.

My issue now is that each $p_{ij}$ is of degree 4. Having polynomials of degree $\geq$ 2 adds additional variables and constraints when we compile $p$ down to a QUBO.

Can we encode these non-overlapping constraints with polynomials of degree < 4?

Comment: If you are going to introduce binary variables, why not represent each disjunction with a binary variable and apply the usual big-M formulation?

Comment: @RobPratt I don't really have an OR background. Could you recommend a compact introduction? At least the German Wikipedia article is less than helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For each pair $(t_i, t_j)$ of tasks with $i < j$, introduce a binary variable $z_{ij}\in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ which will be 0 if $t_i$ precedes $t_j$ and 1 if $t_j$ precedes $t_i$. The approach is to add a pair of constraints representing those two possibilities, such that for each value of $z_{ij}$ one constraint enforces a particular precedence and the other constraint is vacuous (automatically satisfied). Here you would use the following: $$ x(t_i) + d(t_i) - x(t_j) \le T z_{ij}$$ and $$x(t_j) + d(t_j) - x(t_i) \le T(1-z_{ij}).$$ This is what @RobPratt was getting at.

Comment: Thanks, big M works somewhat. But now the optimal solution is spaced out.

More precisely with three variables $x(t_i) \in \{0,...,7\}, i \in \{1,2,3\}$, $d(x_i) = 1 \forall i$,  $T = 16$, $z$ as above. I introduced a slack variable $\xi_{ij} \in \{0,...,7\}$ into each inequality and squared each inequality. Lastly, I added a simple sum over all $x(t_i)$ as objective. Then the optimal solutions (according to my computer) are given by $x_i = 0, x_j = 3, x_k = 7, \, i,j,k \in \sigma({1,2,3})$. These solutions fullfill all constraints but are not optimal w.r.t the objective. What's going on?

Comment: @AlexNe You do not need to add explicit slack variables, and you should not square the inequalities. Just use the (linear) big-M constraints as is.

Comment: What do you mean "as is"? In a QUBO formulation I can't have inequalities. Best I can do is add a slack variable to turn my inequalities into equality constraints, then turn these into minimization problems by squaring and put a sufficiently large lagrange multiplier in front. If I just incorporate the inequalities without squaring, both cancel and we solve $\text{argmin}_x(\sum_i^n d(t_i) - nT + \text{objective}(x))$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use ILP instead of QUBO.